# EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION in Repast

Tags: java, windows-10, repast-simphony

I have installed Repast on my windows 10 computer, but if I try to run one of the demo codes I get an error.

> Error loading EGL entry points.
>
> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000000000000, pid=22096, tid=21896
>
> JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (11.0.4+11) (build 11.0.4+11)
>    Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.4+11, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
>    Problematic frame:
>    C  0x0000000000000000
>
> No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
>
> An error report file with more information is saved as:
>    C:\Surfdrive\Models_and_Scripts\Repast\Zombies_Demo\hs_err_pid22096.log
>
> If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
>      https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-build/issues
>    The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
>    See problematic frame for where to report the bug.

I have tried to run Repast as administrator and set javaw.exe in to run as adminstrator, but that does not solve the problem.

This is the THREAD in the error log file (complete file is too long):
    ---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

```
Current thread (0x000001a735b13800):  JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_in_native, id=21896, stack(0x000000427a300000,0x000000427a400000)]

Stack: [0x000000427a300000,0x000000427a400000],  sp=0x000000427a3f7cd8,  free space=991k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  jogamp.opengl.egl.EGL.dispatch_eglGetProcAddress0(Ljava/lang/String;J)J+0
j  jogamp.opengl.egl.EGL.eglGetProcAddress(JLjava/lang/String;)J+18
j  jogamp.opengl.egl.EGLDynamicLibraryBundleInfo.toolGetProcAddress(JLjava/lang/String;)J+2
j  com.jogamp.common.os.DynamicLibraryBundle.toolDynamicLookupFunction(Ljava/lang/String;)J+18
j  com.jogamp.common.os.DynamicLibraryBundle.dynamicLookupFunction(Ljava/lang/String;)J+94
j  com.jogamp.gluegen.runtime.opengl.GLProcAddressResolver.resolve(Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/jogamp/common/os/DynamicLookupHelper;)J+35
j  com.jogamp.gluegen.runtime.ProcAddressTable.setEntry(Ljava/lang/reflect/Field;Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/jogamp/common/os/DynamicLookupHelper;)V+30
j  com.jogamp.gluegen.runtime.ProcAddressTable.reset(Lcom/jogamp/common/os/DynamicLookupHelper;)V+129
j  jogamp.opengl.egl.EGL.resetProcAddressTable(Lcom/jogamp/common/os/DynamicLookupHelper;)V+4
j  jogamp.opengl.egl.EGLDrawableFactory.<init>()V+294
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
J 2507  jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Constructor;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; java.base@11.0.4 (0 bytes) @ 0x000001a72565a326 [0x000001a72565a2c0+0x0000000000000066]
J 2506 c1 jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; java.base@11.0.4 (89 bytes) @ 0x000001a71e12d6bc [0x000001a71e12cb40+0x0000000000000b7c]
J 2453 c1 jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; java.base@11.0.4 (9 bytes) @ 0x000001a71e0d7edc [0x000001a71e0d7de0+0x00000000000000fc]
J 2452 c1 java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; java.base@11.0.4 (76 bytes) @ 0x000001a71e0e1404 [0x000001a71e0e11a0+0x0000000000000264]
j  com.jogamp.common.util.ReflectionUtil.createInstance(Ljava/lang/reflect/Constructor;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+2
j  com.jogamp.common.util.ReflectionUtil.createInstance(Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6
j  com.jogamp.common.util.ReflectionUtil.createInstance(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Ljava/lang/Object;+8
j  com.jogamp.common.util.ReflectionUtil.createInstance(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Ljava/lang/Object;+4
j  javax.media.opengl.GLDrawableFactory.initSingletonImpl()V+263
j  javax.media.opengl.GLDrawableFactory.initSingleton()V+21
j  javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.initProfilesForDefaultDevices()V+107
j  javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.access$000()V+0
j  javax.media.opengl.GLProfile$1.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+58
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
J 1304  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;)Ljava/lang/Object; java.base@11.0.4 (0 bytes) @ 0x000001a72568b392 [0x000001a72568b340+0x0000000000000052]
j  javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.initSingleton()V+75
j  javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.getProfileMap(Ljavax/media/nativewindow/AbstractGraphicsDevice;Z)Ljava/util/HashMap;+0
j  javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.get(Ljavax/media/nativewindow/AbstractGraphicsDevice;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/media/opengl/GLProfile;+16
j  javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.get(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/media/opengl/GLProfile;+4
j  saf.v3d.Canvas2D.<init>()V+69
j  repast.simphony.visualizationOGL2D.DisplayOGL2D.<init>(Lrepast/simphony/visualization/DisplayData;Lrepast/simphony/visualization/Layout;)V+106
j  repast.simphony.visualization.engine.DisplayCreatorOGL2D.createDisplay()Lrepast/simphony/visualization/IDisplay;+65
j  repast.simphony.visualization.engine.DisplayProducer.createDisplay()Lrepast/simphony/visualization/IDisplay;+35
j  repast.simphony.visualization.engine.DisplayComponentControllerAction.runInitialize(Lrepast/simphony/engine/environment/RunState;Ljava/lang/Object;Lrepast/simphony/parameter/Parameters;)V+304
j  repast.simphony.engine.controller.DefaultController$3.visit(Lrepast/simphony/engine/environment/ControllerAction;)V+18
j  repast.simphony.engine.controller.DefaultController$3.visit(Ljava/lang/Object;)V+5
j  repast.simphony.util.collections.NaryTree.preOrderTraverals(Lrepast/simphony/util/collections/NaryTree$Node;Lrepast/simphony/util/collections/TreeVisitor;)V+5
j  repast.simphony.util.collections.NaryTree.preOrderTraverals(Lrepast/simphony/util/collections/NaryTree$Node;Lrepast/simphony/util/collections/TreeVisitor;)V+45
j  repast.simphony.util.collections.NaryTree.preOrderTraverals(Lrepast/simphony/util/collections/NaryTree$Node;Lrepast/simphony/util/collections/TreeVisitor;)V+45
j  repast.simphony.util.collections.NaryTree.preOrderTraversal(Lrepast/simphony/util/collections/TreeVisitor;)V+6
j  repast.simphony.engine.controller.DefaultController.runInitialize(Lrepast/simphony/engine/environment/RunState;Lrepast/simphony/context/Context;Lrepast/simphony/parameter/Parameters;)V+101
j  repast.simphony.engine.controller.DefaultController.runInitialize(Lrepast/simphony/parameter/Parameters;)Lrepast/simphony/engine/environment/RunState;+111
j  repast.simphony.ui.RSApplication.initSim()V+44
j  repast.simphony.ui.action.InitRun.actionPerformed(Ljava/awt/event/ActionEvent;)V+10
j  javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Ljava/awt/event/ActionEvent;)V+83 java.desktop@11.0.4
j  javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Ljava/awt/event/ActionEvent;)V+5 java.desktop@11.0.4
j  javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Ljava/awt/event/ActionEvent;)V+34 java.desktop@11.0.4
j  javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Z)V+117 java.desktop@11.0.4
j  javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Ljava/awt/event/MouseEvent;)V+35 java.desktop@11.0.4
j  java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Ljava/awt/event/MouseEvent;)V+8 java.desktop@11.0.4
j  java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Ljava/awt/event/MouseEvent;)V+64 java.desktop@11.0.4
j  javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Ljava/awt/event/MouseEvent;)V+23 java.desktop@11.0.4
j  java.awt.Component.processEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+81 java.desktop@11.0.4
J 4777 c1 java.awt.Container.processEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V java.desktop@11.0.4 (22 bytes) @ 0x000001a71ea43a24 [0x000001a71ea43700+0x0000000000000324]
J 4654 c1 java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V java.desktop@11.0.4 (777 bytes) @ 0x000001a71e9fd454 [0x000001a71e9f9840+0x0000000000003c14]
J 4653 c1 java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V java.desktop@11.0.4 (129 bytes) @ 0x000001a71e9f839c [0x000001a71e9f8260+0x000000000000013c]
J 4631 c1 java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V java.desktop@11.0.4 (6 bytes) @ 0x000001a71e9e5f34 [0x000001a71e9e5e40+0x00000000000000f4]
j  java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Ljava/awt/Component;ILjava/awt/event/MouseEvent;)V+349 java.desktop@11.0.4
j  java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Ljava/awt/event/MouseEvent;)Z+155 java.desktop@11.0.4
j  java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)Z+50 java.desktop@11.0.4
J 4653 c1 java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V java.desktop@11.0.4 (129 bytes) @ 0x000001a71e9f833c [0x000001a71e9f8260+0x00000000000000dc]
j  java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V+19 java.desktop@11.0.4
J 4741 c1 java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;Ljava/lang/Object;)V java.desktop@11.0.4 (136 bytes) @ 0x000001a71ea2c454 [0x000001a71ea2bfc0+0x0000000000000494]
J 4740 c1 java.awt.EventQueue$4.run()Ljava/lang/Void; java.desktop@11.0.4 (60 bytes) @ 0x000001a71ea2b82c [0x000001a71ea2b700+0x000000000000012c]
J 4739 c1 java.awt.EventQueue$4.run()Ljava/lang/Object; java.desktop@11.0.4 (5 bytes) @ 0x000001a71ea2b344 [0x000001a71ea2b2c0+0x0000000000000084]
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
J 2083  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object; java.base@11.0.4 (0 bytes) @ 0x000001a7256ff326 [0x000001a7256ff2c0+0x0000000000000066]
J 4651 c1 java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object; java.base@11.0.4 (22 bytes) @ 0x000001a71e9f54ac [0x000001a71e9f51a0+0x000000000000030c]
j  java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6 java.base@11.0.4
j  java.awt.EventQueue$5.run()Ljava/lang/Void;+11 java.desktop@11.0.4
j  java.awt.EventQueue$5.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+1 java.desktop@11.0.4
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
J 2083  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object; java.base@11.0.4 (0 bytes) @ 0x000001a7256ff326 [0x000001a7256ff2c0+0x0000000000000066]
J 4672 c1 java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Ljava/awt/AWTEvent;)V java.desktop@11.0.4 (80 bytes) @ 0x000001a71ea0c16c [0x000001a71ea0b6a0+0x0000000000000acc]
J 4746 c1 java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(I)V java.desktop@11.0.4 (113 bytes) @ 0x000001a71ea323ac [0x000001a71ea31ca0+0x000000000000070c]
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(ILjava/awt/Conditional;Ljava/awt/EventFilter;)V+35 java.desktop@11.0.4
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(ILjava/awt/Conditional;Ljava/awt/Component;)V+11 java.desktop@11.0.4
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(ILjava/awt/Conditional;)V+4 java.desktop@11.0.4
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Ljava/awt/Conditional;)V+3 java.desktop@11.0.4
j  java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run()V+9 java.desktop@11.0.4
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

siginfo: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005), data execution prevention violation at address 0x0000000000000000


Register to memory mapping:

RIP=0x0 is NULL
RAX=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
RBX=0x000001a735b13b40 points into unknown readable memory: 40 6c 21 0c fe 7f 00 00
RCX=0x000001a737c29430 points into unknown readable memory: 65 67 6c 42 69 6e 64 41
RDX=0x00007ffe4be9e0e0 libEGL.dll
RSP=0x000000427a3f7cd8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000001a735b13800
RBP=0x00007ffe4be819f6 libEGL.dll
RSI=0x000000427a3f7de8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000001a735b13800
RDI=0x000001a737c29430 points into unknown readable memory: 65 67 6c 42 69 6e 64 41
R8 =0x00007ffe4be9faa0 libEGL.dll
R9 =0x00007ffe4be9302a libEGL.dll
R10=0x0 is NULL
R11=0x000000427a3f7a80 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000001a735b13800
R12=0x0 is NULL
R13={method} {0x000001a7406c1478} 'dispatch_eglGetProcAddress0' '(Ljava/lang/String;J)J' in 'jogamp/opengl/egl/EGL'
R14=0x000000427a3f7de8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000001a735b13800
R15=0x000001a735b13800 is a thread


Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000001, RBX=0x000001a735b13b40, RCX=0x000001a737c29430, RDX=0x00007ffe4be9e0e0
RSP=0x000000427a3f7cd8, RBP=0x00007ffe4be819f6, RSI=0x000000427a3f7de8, RDI=0x000001a737c29430
R8 =0x00007ffe4be9faa0, R9 =0x00007ffe4be9302a, R10=0x0000000000000000, R11=0x000000427a3f7a80
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x000001a7406c1470, R14=0x000000427a3f7de8, R15=0x000001a735b13800
RIP=0x0000000000000000, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010202

Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000427a3f7cd8)
0x000000427a3f7cd8:   0000000064361292 000001a735b13b40
0x000000427a3f7ce8:   00007ffe4be819f6 000000427a3f7de8
0x000000427a3f7cf8:   000001a71db2ee80 000000427a3f8500
0x000000427a3f7d08:   000001a7406c1470 000000003845e4ea
0x000000427a3f7d18:   0000000000001f40 000000427a3f7db8
0x000000427a3f7d28:   000001a71db2f037 0000000000001f40
0x000000427a3f7d38:   000001a71db2ed1c 000001a735b13800
0x000000427a3f7d48:   000001a7406c1470 000000427a3f7db8
0x000000427a3f7d58:   000000003845e4ea 000000003845e4ea
0x000000427a3f7d68:   000001a71db2ecd6 000000427a3f7d70
0x000000427a3f7d78:   000001a7406c1470 000000427a3f7de8
0x000000427a3f7d88:   000001a7406c2fa8 0000000000000000
0x000000427a3f7d98:   0000000087bf8b68 000001a7406c1470
0x000000427a3f7da8:   0000000000000000 000000427a3f7dd8
0x000000427a3f7db8:   000000427a3f7e38 000001a71db29910
0x000000427a3f7dc8:   0000000087bf8b68 000001a71db2bf97 

Instructions: (pc=0x0000000000000000)
0xffffffffffffff00:   


Stack slot to memory mapping:
stack at sp + 0 slots: 0x0000000064361292 jogl_mobile.dll
stack at sp + 1 slots: 0x000001a735b13b40 points into unknown readable memory: 40 6c 21 0c fe 7f 00 00
stack at sp + 2 slots: 0x00007ffe4be819f6 libEGL.dll
stack at sp + 3 slots: 0x000000427a3f7de8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000001a735b13800
stack at sp + 4 slots: 0x000001a71db2ee80 is at code_begin+608 in an Interpreter codelet
method entry point (kind = native)  [0x000001a71db2ec20, 0x000001a71db2f780]  2912 bytes
stack at sp + 5 slots: 0x000000427a3f8500 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000001a735b13800
stack at sp + 6 slots: {method} {0x000001a7406c1478} 'dispatch_eglGetProcAddress0' '(Ljava/lang/String;J)J' in 'jogamp/opengl/egl/EGL'
stack at sp + 7 slots: 0x000000003845e4ea is an unknown value
```

Thanks a lot in advance for answering.
Egil

Comment: Can you post the contents of the error log file that is described in the error message.

Comment: The log is very long unfortunatly. I will post the part that I think are most usefule

Comment: --------------  S U M M A R Y ------------

Command Line: -XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM --add-exports=java.base/jdk.internal.ref=ALL-UNNAMED -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 repast.simphony.runtime.RepastMain C:\Surfdrive\Models_and_Scripts\Repast\Zombies_Demo/Zombies_Demo.rs

Host: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz, 8 cores, 7G,  Windows 10 , 64 bit Build 17763 (10.0.17763.1158)
Time: Thu May 28 15:54:58 2020 W. Europe Daylight Time elapsed time: 14 seconds (0d 0h 0m 14s)

Comment: Environment Variables:
PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Rtools\bin;C:\Rtools\mingw_64\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Asymptote;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\fisch106\AppData\Local\Programs\orca;C:\Users\fisch106\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps

Comment: USERNAME=Fisch106
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 142 Stepping 10, GenuineIntel

---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 10 , 64 bit Build 17763 (10.0.17763.1158)

CPU:total 8 (initial active 8) (4 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 142 stepping 10, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, avx2, aes, clmul, erms, 3dnowpref, lzcnt, ht, tsc, tscinvbit, bmi1, bmi2, adx, fma

Comment: Memory: 4k page, system-wide physical 8035M (1274M free)
TotalPageFile size 12899M (AvailPageFile size 2182M)
current process WorkingSet (physical memory assigned to process): 324M, peak: 331M
current process commit charge ("private bytes"): 365M, peak: 374M

vm_info: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.4+11) for windows-amd64 JRE (11.0.4+11), built on Jul 18 2019 06:43:34 by "" with MS VC++ 15.8 (VS2017)

END.

Comment: Please try to post the entire log file by editing your original post and not in the comments.  Unfortunately the parts you posted did not contain any clues.

Comment: Thanks a lot Eric Tatara for trying to help me. I did now add the Thread of the error log. The complete error log is just too long to post unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error log, it appears to be an issue with the graphics driver on your PC.  Are you using a standard Windows PC or laptop, or something like a mobile tablet or chromebook?  The error suggests an issue trying to load a mobile graphics driver and this would not occur if used on a PC.  Which demo in particular causes this error?  Is it a standard demo, or a "Server" demo launch?

One suggestd approach that solves graphics problems with Repast displays is to update the graphics driver on your PC.  If you have and NVidia or AMD GPU you can download a driver update utility from their websites.

Comment: Thanks Eric, I am using a standard laptop (windows 10), but issued through the ICT services of my University hence not in complete control. The error occurs in the standard demo's. Both the groovy and java versions.
I will try your suggestion.

Comment: Updating the graphics driver did not do the job unfortunately. I can run the demo models in batch.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking libEGL.dll of your PATH environment. Re mingw_64.